# Visual Basic not writing to SQL backend

Tags: vb.net

I am having trouble figuring out why my updates and inserts aren't writing to SQL Server backend. I do not have much visual basic experience and am wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction.

```
Protected Sub CatNutritionTypes_RowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs)
        Try

            Using sqlCon As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(Azure_Connection_String)
                sqlCon.Open()
                Dim query As String = "UPDATE Norm.CAT_Nutrition_Types SET Genesis_NutrientKey=@Genesis_NutrientKey, CAT_UOMID=@CAT_UOMID, IsViewable=@IsViewable, IsDailyValue=@IsDailyValue, IsCalculated=@IsCalculated, IsUserCreated=@IsUserCreated, CAT_Nutrient_Group_ID=@CAT_Nutrient_Group_ID, Genesis_API_GUID=@Genesis_API_GUID, EnteredDateTime=@EnteredDateTime, UserID=@UserID, IsDeleted=@IsDeleted, DeletedDateTime=@DeletedDateTime, IsRequired=@IsRequired, OrderBy=@OrderBy, Percent_Diff=@Percent_Diff  WHERE CAT_Nutrition_TypesID = @id"
                Dim sqlCmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(query, sqlCon)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Genesis_NutrientKey", (TryCast(CatNutritionTypes.FooterRow.FindControl("txtGenesisNutrientKey"), TextBox)).Text.Trim())
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nutritional_Desc", (TryCast(CatNutritionTypes.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNutritionalDesc"), TextBox)).Text.Trim())
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AbbreviatedName", (TryCast(CatNutritionTypes.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAbbreviatedName"), TextBox)).Text.Trim())
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CAT_UOMID", (TryCast(CatNutritionTypes.FooterRow.FindControl("txtCatUomId"), TextBox)).Text.Trim())
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsViewable", (TryCast(CatNutritionTypes.FooterRow.FindControl("txtIsViewable"), CheckBox)).Text.Trim())
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsDailyValue", (TryCast(CatNutritionTypes.FooterRow.FindControl("txtIsDailyValue"), CheckBox)).Text.Trim())
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsCalculated", (TryCast(CatNutritionTypes.FooterRow.FindControl("txtIsCalculated"), CheckBox)).Text.Trim())
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsUserCreated", (TryCast(CatNutritionTypes.FooterRow.FindControl("txtIsUserCreated"), CheckBox)).Text.Trim())
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CAT_Nutrient_Group_ID", (TryCast(CatNutritionTypes.FooterRow.FindControl("txtCatNutrientGroupId"), TextBox)).Text.Trim())
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Genesis_API_GUID", (TryCast(CatNutritionTypes.FooterRow.FindControl("txtGenesisApiGuid"), TextBox)).Text.Trim())
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EnteredDateTime", (TryCast(CatNutritionTypes.FooterRow.FindControl("txtEnteredDateTime"), TextBox)).Text.Trim())
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", (TryCast(CatNutritionTypes.FooterRow.FindControl("txtUserId"), TextBox)).Text.Trim())
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsDeleted", (TryCast(CatNutritionTypes.FooterRow.FindControl("txtIsDeleted"), CheckBox)).Text.Trim())
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeletedDateTime", (TryCast(CatNutritionTypes.FooterRow.FindControl("txtDeletedDateTime"), TextBox)).Text.Trim())
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsRequired", (TryCast(CatNutritionTypes.FooterRow.FindControl("txtIsRequired"), CheckBox)).Text.Trim())
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderBy", (TryCast(CatNutritionTypes.FooterRow.FindControl("txtOrderBy"), TextBox)).Text.Trim())
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Percent_Diff", (TryCast(CatNutritionTypes.FooterRow.FindControl("txtPercentDiff"), TextBox)).Text.Trim())
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(CatNutritionTypes.DataKeys(e.RowIndex).Value.ToString()))
                sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                CatNutritionTypes.EditIndex = -1
                PopulateGridview()
                lblSuccessMessage.Text = "Selected Record Updated"
                lblErrorMessage.Text = ""
            End Using

        Catch ex As Exception
            lblSuccessMessage.Text = ""
            lblErrorMessage.Text = ex.Message
        End Try
    End Sub

Protected Sub CatNutritionTypes_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)
    Try

        If e.CommandName.Equals("AddNew") Then

            Using sqlCon As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(Azure_Connection_String)
                sqlCon.Open()
                Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO Norm.CAT_Nutrition_Types (Genesis_NutrientKey, Nutritional_Desc, AbbreviatedName, CAT_UOMID, IsViewable, IsDailyValue, IsCalculated, IsUserCreated, CAT_Nutrient_Group, Genesis_API_GUID,  EnteredDateTime, UserID, IsDeleted, DeletedDateTime, IsRequired, OrderBy, Percent_Diff) VALUES (@Genesis_NutrientKey, @Nutritional_Desc, @AbbreviatedName, @CAT_UOMID, @IsViewable, @IsDailyValue, @IsCalculated, @IsUserCreated, @CAT_Nutrient_Group, @Genesis_API_GUID,  @EnteredDateTime, @UserID, @IsDeleted, @DeletedDateTime, @IsRequired, @OrderBy, @Percent_Diff)"
                Dim sqlCmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(query, sqlCon)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Genesis_NutrientKey", (TryCast(CatNutritionTypes.FooterRow.FindControl("txtGenesisNutrientKeyFooter"), TextBox)).Text.Trim())
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nutritional_Desc", (TryCast(CatNutritionTypes.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNutritionalDescFooter"), TextBox)).Text.Trim())
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AbbreviatedName", (TryCast(CatNutritionTypes.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAbbreviatedNameFooter"), TextBox)).Text.Trim())
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CAT_UOMID", (TryCast(CatNutritionTypes.FooterRow.FindControl("txtCatUomIdFooter"), TextBox)).Text.Trim())
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsViewable", (TryCast(CatNutritionTypes.FooterRow.FindControl("txtIsViewableFooter"), CheckBox)).Text.Trim())
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsDailyValue", (TryCast(CatNutritionTypes.FooterRow.FindControl("txtIsDailyValueFooter"), CheckBox)).Text.Trim())
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsCalculated", (TryCast(CatNutritionTypes.FooterRow.FindControl("txtIsCalculatedFooter"), CheckBox)).Text.Trim())
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsUserCreated", (TryCast(CatNutritionTypes.FooterRow.FindControl("txtIsUserCreatedFooter"), CheckBox)).Text.Trim())
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CAT_Nutrient_Group_ID", (TryCast(CatNutritionTypes.FooterRow.FindControl("txtCatNutrientGroupIdFooter"), TextBox)).Text.Trim())
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Genesis_API_GUID", (TryCast(CatNutritionTypes.FooterRow.FindControl("txtGenesisApiGuidFooter"), TextBox)).Text.Trim())
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EnteredDateTime", (TryCast(CatNutritionTypes.FooterRow.FindControl("txtEnteredDateTimeFooter"), TextBox)).Text.Trim())
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", (TryCast(CatNutritionTypes.FooterRow.FindControl("txtUserIdFooter"), TextBox)).Text.Trim())
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsDeleted", (TryCast(CatNutritionTypes.FooterRow.FindControl("txtIsDeletedFooter"), CheckBox)).Text.Trim())
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeletedDateTime", (TryCast(CatNutritionTypes.FooterRow.FindControl("txtDeletedDateTimeFooter"), TextBox)).Text.Trim())
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsRequired", (TryCast(CatNutritionTypes.FooterRow.FindControl("txtIsRequiredFooter"), CheckBox)).Text.Trim())
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderBy", (TryCast(CatNutritionTypes.FooterRow.FindControl("txtOrderByFooter"), TextBox)).Text.Trim())
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Percent_Diff", (TryCast(CatNutritionTypes.FooterRow.FindControl("txtPercentDiffFooter"), TextBox)).Text.Trim())
                sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                PopulateGridview()
                lblSuccessMessage.Text = "New Record Added"
                lblErrorMessage.Text = ""

            End Using
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        lblSuccessMessage.Text = ""
        lblErrorMessage.Text = ex.Message
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: I believe AddWithValue is generally considered problematic. You'd be better off creating a parameter and then assigning its value. Can I suggest splitting this into a few methods. One to get the data values from the gridview. One to receive data values, build the sql and execute it. What result are you getting from `ExecuteNonQuery` ?

Comment: @AndrewMortimer I wrote the book on the AddWithValue() issue. Yes, it's problematic, but he should be okay in this case. For an UPDATE where you have a specific integer ID value, as long as you get that ID right (and forcing Convert.ToInt32() will ensure that), you'll avoid needing to do table or index scans or the bad per-row value conversions.

Comment: Can you add how you come to the conclusion that the Database is not being updated please? - Are you relying on the GridView you use or another method?

Comment: On another note. In the Sub `CatNutritionTypes_RowUpdating` you are adding the parameters: _Nutritional_Desc_ and _AbbreviatedName_ but they are not in the Sql statement to update a corresponding column

Comment: This parameter looks problematic. `sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsViewable", (TryCast(CatNutritionTypes.FooterRow.FindControl("txtIsViewable"), CheckBox)).Text.Trim())` A check box's .Text property is the value in the label associated with the check box. I would guess this field is a Boolean (Bit in Sql Server) and you are passing a string with a value that cannot be converted to bit.

Comment: @JayV I was able to add rows on the front end website, but they didnt persist to the backend sql table

Comment: What happens if you comment out the exception handling block (`Catch ex As Exception`) ? It is conceivable that errors are being triggered but you don't see them.

Comment: @AndrewMortimer  I was under the impression that the executenonquery() would allow updates or inserts to be written to sql, but it doesnt seem to be working

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery returns the number of rows affected in by your SQL command, what's the value your getting back there?

Comment: @hursey no value.  Executenonquery doesnt return anything as it is only used for updates and inserts. I think executequery is used to return rows.

Comment: That would suggest to me, there isn't something right with the filtering @id parameter.  Either the value of Convert.ToInt32(CatNutritionTypes.DataKeys(e.RowIndex).Value.ToString()) is not what your expecting, or that id simply doesn't existing in your db.  From here, this is really just a straight debugging issue.  As suggested above, maybe move to using typed parameters rather than AddWithValue(), make sure all your types line up and problem might just sort it self out